# Reshaping mfdataset files faster with Xarray and Dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I'm trying to use Dask in combination with Xarray to load a dataset dowloaded from [ecmwf](https://www.ecmwf.int). That data is stored in `netcdf` files split along the time axis in months. They are 3 hour stepped samples for 8 variables in each file.

I want to re-save this dataset as a file per latitude/longitude index for the entire time span. So going from `lat=all, lng=all, time=months` to `lat=1, lng=1, time=all`.

However, I'm not sure how to get better performance out of this, it seems to be slower than what I'd expect currently - even just the preprocessing. Feel like I must be doing some stuff sub optimally.

Here's the steps I use and there speeds:

1. Loading. This is pretty quick. The full dataset `xarray.open_mfdataset` finishes in about 60 seconds with the cluster being used. I had tried to load with `chunks=dict(time=-1, latitude=1, longitude=1)` to try and let Dask know this is how I'm planning on accessing the data, but the chunks of the `data_vars` seemed to stay the same and ignored the chunks argument going into `xarray.open_mfdataset`.

```
import xarray as xr
from dask.distributed import Client

c = Client("scheduler:8786")
c.cluster

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(
    "/resource_data/ecmwf/era20c/grid-av/hour-step-3/*.nc",
    parallel=True,
    # chunks=dict(time=-1, latitude=1, longitude=1)
)
print(ds)
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 240, latitude: 121, time: 321664)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 1.5 3.0 4.5 ... 354.0 355.5 357.0 358.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 88.5 87.0 85.5 ... -87.0 -88.5 -90.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1900-01-01 ... 2010-01-31T21:00:00
Data variables:
    mp1        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    wind       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    mwd        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    dwi        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    swh        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    pp1d       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    mp2        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
    mwp        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(248, 121, 240), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2019-11-22 10:06:28 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.14.1
```

2. Next I try and prepare from datasets for `xarray.save_mfdataset`. Originally I was going to try something like `Xarray.Dataset.groupby`, but that doesn't currently support multiple items (i.e. `ds.groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])`), so manually making these sub-sets and save paths for `xarray.save_mfdataset` as follows. This is pretty slow:

```
lat_lngs = list(itertools.product(ds.latitude.values, ds.longitude.values))

datasets = []
paths = []

for lat, lng in lat_lngs:
    save_path = os.path.join(out_dir, f"lat_{lat}_lng_{lng}.h5")
    dataset = ds.sel(latitude=lat, longitude=lng)

    datasets.append(dataset)
    paths.append(save_path)

os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

delayed = xr.save_mfdataset(
    datasets,
    paths,
    engine="h5netcdf",
    compute=False,
)

c.persist(delayed, optimize_graph=True)
```

The native python for-loop collecting the paths and the datasets takes about 40 seconds, but the `xr.save_mfdataset` has been running for 40 *minutes* as of writing this, and this isn't even starting 'the work' (I believe that should happen on call to persist after).

Any tips on how I should go about optimising this? or does this seem expected / reasonable?

Comment: Are yo aware of https://github.com/pangeo-data/rechunker ?

Comment: I was aware, thanks. It looks interesting though from the small bit of documentation it seems to be for the Zarr format. Open to whatever's best to store the output in, but the input is netcdf at the moment.

Comment: The output is zarr, but I thought the input could be other netCDF-like things.

Comment: You are correct, I could give it a Xarray Dataset, though the data I have is split by month so the time chunk is inconsistent. This raises an error in rechunker unfortunately. Might require more playing around on my side to get something to work. thanks for the suggestion